# local storage data not rendered

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

currently i'm making an e commerce website. I want to store the order data by user on local storage. here's my code:

details.vue

```
import DataService from '../web_service/services'

export default {
  name: 'details',
  props: ['userId'],
  data () {
    return {
      datas: null,
      url: '/' + this.userId,
      value: 1
    }
  },
  created () {
    DataService.getFindById(this.url)
      .then((res) => {
        this.datas = res.data.data
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        alert('error when fetching API' + err)
      })
  },
  methods: {
    buyNow () {
      let order = {
        product: this.datas.name,
        price: this.datas.price,
        quantity: this.value
      }

      this.$store.commit('addOrder', order)
      this.$router.push('/cart')
    }
  }
}
```

store.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'

Vue.use(Vuex)

export default new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
        order: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("order")),
    },
    mutations: {
        addOrder: (state, product) => {
            const arrProduct = []
            const parse = JSON.stringify(product)
            state.order = parse

            localStorage.setItem('order', parse)
        }
    }
})
```

shopCart.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="shopCart>
  <b-card-body>
          <b-card-text>
            <div v-if="orders" class="float-left">
              <h5>{{orders.product}}</h5>
              <h5>{{orders.price}}</h5>
            </div>
          </b-card-text>
        </b-card-body>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
    name: 'shopCart',
    data () {
        return {
            orders: null
        }
    },
    created () {
        this.orders = this.$store.state.order
        
    }
}   
</script>
```

when i'm trying to take order scenario, it direct to `/cart` routes then show my item. However, my order data is not rendered. When i refresh the page, it shows my order data. Does anyone know the solution ? thanks in advance !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Everything is working except that you've set the `order` to the parsed string that was meant for `localStorage`.  So when you view the cart page, `orders.product` and `orders.price` are undefined, even though the `v-if` is `true`.

Change your mutation:

```js
addOrder: (state, product) => {
   const arrProduct = []
   const parse = JSON.stringify(product)
   state.order = product;    // ✅ Set this to the product, not a string

   localStorage.setItem('order', parse)
}
```